# python regex: not giving the group it matches

Tags: python, regex

Here is the pattern

```
pattern_strings = ['\\xc2d', '\\xa0', '\\xe7', '\\xc3\\ufffdd', '\\xc2\\xa0', '\\xc3\\xa7', '\\xa0\\xa0', '\\xc2', '\\xe9']
join_pattern =  '[' + '|'.join(pattern_strings) + ']'
pattern = re.compile(join_pattern)
```

Here is the function

```
def find_pattern(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # print line
            found = pattern.search(line)
            if found:
                print dir(found)
                logging.info('found in line - ' + line)
                logging.info('found - ' + str(found.group(0)))
```

Here is the input

```
\xc2d 
d\xa0 
\xe7 
\xc3\ufffdd 
\xc3\ufffdd 
\xc2\xa0 
\xc3\xa7 
\xa0\xa0 
'619d813\xa03697'
```

When I run this, I get output as

```
INFO:root:found in line - \xc2d 

INFO:root:found - d
INFO:root:found in line - d\xa0 

INFO:root:found - d
INFO:root:found in line - \xc3\ufffdd 

INFO:root:found - u
INFO:root:found in line - \xc3\ufffdd 

INFO:root:found - u
INFO:root:found in line - '619d813\xa03697' 

INFO:root:found - d
```

**Question**
- Why doesn't it tells the entire pattern like `\xc2d`? am I doing something incorrect here?
- What is that I need to do in order to get the pattern matched like `\xc2d` instead of `d`

**UPDATE**

chaging to `join_pattern =  '(' + '|'.join(pattern_strings) + ')'` doesn't matches anything

**UPDATE 1**

```
pattern_strings = ['\\xc2d', '\\xa0', '\\xe7', '\\xc3\\ufffdd', '\\xc2\\xa0', '\\xc3\\xa7', '\\xa0\\xa0', '\\xc2', '\\xe9']

join_pattern =   '|'.join(pattern_strings)
pattern = re.compile(join_pattern)
```

This doesn't matches anything in input :(

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to match one of the strings in `pattern_strings`? Don't encapsulate the regex in square brackets. That denotes a set.

Comment: Why do people so often post answers as comments?

Comment: Your problem is `[` and `]` in your pattern - remove them!

Comment: @AbeKarplus - because answer should be complex, otherwise it is just comment

Comment: Repalce the outer `[ ]` with `(?:    )`.  The square brackets only match single characters, not alternative patterns.

Comment: @cdarke - Why? Not needed. Just to remove square brackets - that's it!

Comment: @Ωmega: because `join_pattern` might be embedded in other text.

Comment: @cdarke - Still don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets in `re` denotes a *set*

`join_pattern =  '[' + '|'.join(pattern_strings) + ']'` causes the regex to match "any one of the set of characters in `{ \ x c 2 d a 0 e 7 3 u f 9 | }`". This is probably not the behavior you want. For the expression you want just use:

```
join_pattern = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
```

No need for parentheses, unlesss you are trying to specify capture/non-capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have surrounded the regular expression with square brackets, `[]`. These indicate a set of characters; that is, `[abc|def]` will match one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `|`, `d`, `e`, or `f`. With the regular expression you have, no parentheses are needed. If this was part of a larger expression, you could use round parentheses `()` to denote a group, which does group together a section of the regular expression. (It also is a capturing group, so its contents could be accessed with `.group(1)`.)